# Python 3: for loop not working, can't seem to work out what's wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
message = "¯¹ÿ½Đ8ȸjŻċŉĀƚâɎ;ǫŹ¨ɔŵɐďȴǫŔlƩ"
def encrypt(message):
    for k in message:
        k += chr(ord(k) * 2)
    return print(k)
encrypt(message)
```

the output is usually one or two characters, when it should encrypt the whole string. Any fix? Total beginner by the way

Comment: `k` is looping through each character in your message, but you also seem to be trying to use it to accumulate your return value. Use a separate variable for that.

Comment: You're printing the last value of `k` where `k` is equal to `chr(ord(c) * 2)` where `c` is the last letter of `message`. Guessing you'd rather want to add `chr(ord(k) * 2)
` to a different variable and return that.

Comment: Others have pointed out errors with your code.  However, the code is more succinctly written as a list comprehension: `def encrypt(message): return ''.join(chr(ord(k)*2) for k in message)`

Answer (score 0):

- You append to the variable loop `k`. you should use a new variable as the loop variable updated each iteration.
- You return the expression `print(k)` is None.

```
message = "¯¹ÿ½Đ8ȸjŻċŉĀƚâɎ;ǫŹ¨ɔŵɐďȴǫŔlƩ"
def encrypt(message):
    ss = ""
    for k in message:
        ss += chr(ord(k) * 2)
    return ss
encrypt(message)
```

Comment: thanks, working perfectly, mind giving me an insight on what was wrong?

Comment: k is a temporary variable and its value is updating as loop increments, you must store the value in a temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

you must store the updated value in another variable

```
message = "¯¹ÿ½Đ8ȸjŻċŉĀƚâɎ;ǫŹ¨ɔŵɐďȴǫŔlƩ"
def encrypt(message):
    temp = ''
    for k in message:
        temp += chr(ord(k) * 2)
    return print(temp)
encrypt(message)
```